# How do I configure "hedera-local-node" to to connect to hedera testnet?

Tags: json-rpc, hedera-hashgraph, hedera

I'm trying to run a Hedera local node locally,
and I'm following the [docker set up instructions](https://hedera.com/blog/how-to-set-up-your-own-hedera-local-network-using-docker)
followed by [these instructions](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/sdks/set-up-your-local-network) to set up a localhost network,
but then hoping to change the connection settings to be able to connect to Hedera Testnet,
instead of my own private network.

The ["network specific configuration"](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-local-node#network-specific-configuration) section of the README seems to imply that this is possible:

> Network specific configurations can be applied using the -n/--network option when starting/restarting the local node. Pre-configured options are mainnet, previewnet, testnet and local
>
> To create a custom network configuration, create a configs folder in the root of your project, then inside create <config_name>.json config file.
>
> You can apply the configuration using the -n/--network options, e.g. hedera start --network <config_name>

... and the repo does contain `configs/testnet.json`.

However I'm not sure how to actually use this.
How can I configure this project so that when it runs,
it connects to the Hedera Testnet instead?

---

Details: After running `docker-compose up -d`, I'm able to access both the mirror node REST APIs, as well as the standard JSON-RPC endpoints:

```bash
curl http://localhost:5551/api/v1/transactions
```

```json
{"transactions":[{"bytes":null,"charged_tx_fee":0,"consensus_timestamp":"1682040490.496223130","entity_id":null,"max_fee":"10000","memo_base64":"MTY4MjA0MDQ5MDQ2OSBNb25pdG9yIHBpbmdlciBvbiBiNzgwMWRkM2Y3NTI=","name":"CRYPTOTRANSFER","node":"0.0.3","nonce":0,"parent_consensus_timestamp":null,"result":"SUCCESS","scheduled":false,"staking_reward_transfers":[],"transaction_hash":"PeUl+/RYyqZx59GMkycTLVaCQ6t6QCuAAQfs02srK1qv/PxE5Gq+RBip0V+8Gvlm","transaction_id":"0.0.2-1682040481-853424739","transfers":[{"account":"0.0.2","amount":-1,"is_approval":false},{"account":"0.0.55","amount":1,"is_approval":false}],"valid_duration_seconds":"120","valid_start_timestamp":"1682040481.853424739"},{"bytes":null,"charged_tx_fee":0,"consensus_timestamp":"1682040489.495783796","entity_id":null,
...
```

```bash
curl \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST \
    --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"web3_clientVersion", "params":[], "id":1234}' \
    http://localhost:7546/
```

```json
{"result":"relay/0.20.1","jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1234}
```

```bash
curl \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST \
    --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_chainId", "params":[], "id":1234}' \
    http://localhost:7546/
```

```json
{"result":"0x12a","jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1234}
```

Note that the chain ID in the RPC response (`298`) does not match that of Hedera Testnet (`296`).

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not described in the README this is not what those network configurations are useful for.  Mostly the only one really useful for an individual developer is the `local` one.

The others are used to duplicate, in your local node on your local machine, the network conditions of the named network (e.g., `testnet`).  So I guess that would be useful if you're developing a wallet and want to make sure it can do things on `mainnet` without actually talking to mainnet.  Start your local node with the `mainnet` configuration, point your wallet to it, and that'll make sure your `chainid` and other configuration things in your wallet are correct.  If that's useful.

W.r.t. your real question

> How can I configure this project so that when it runs, it connects to the Hedera Testnet instead?

That can't happen.  Hedera (at least currently, 2023-05) is a *permissioned* network.  The consensus nodes that run on `testnet` (or `mainnet`, `previewnet`) are fixed (in a given release) and they all know about each other.  They only talk to each other and won't talk to anyone else (for consensus; obviously anyone can talk to them to submit a transaction or query).  So you can't, now, just "join" `testnet`.

- That's for the consensus nodes.  The *output* of the consensus nodes, from which you can establish the entire state of the Hedera store and keep track of its evolution as transactions happen, are *record stream files* which are stored in the cloud.  You can set up your own mirror node to *pull* [those files](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-mirror-node/blob/27655f8ddceb7e65df98253c8a8999c824f31c47/hedera-mirror-importer/src/main/java/com/hedera/mirror/importer/MirrorProperties.java#L84) (historical, as well as in real-time as they're written) to keep track of the state of Hedera.  And people have done that ([including commercially](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/core-concepts/mirror-nodes/hedera-mirror-node#mainnet).)

Comment: Thanks - very useful - One thing I was looking for (unstated in my OP) is whether it is possible to run a Hedera node on Testnet, but disable only the consensus part of it (hashgraph)... but you've answered that as well, in that seems to be exactly what a Hedera Mirror node does!